# EzPublish does not find his routes

Tags: php, symfony, routes, ezpublish, ezplatform

I have installed ez publish (version: community 15.09, system: apache).

I have installed it in my public_html dir, and the public directory is 
public_html/web

I can access to the demo page with this URL:

```
domain.com/
```

or with this (both version)

```
domani.com/index.php
```

but if I try another route, like this:

```
domain.com/ez
```

it not work (the server reply: `The requested URL /ez was not found on this server.`), work only if I include the index in the route:

```
domain.com/index.php/ez
```

I searched but found nothing... 
Why this?
How to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is basically url rewriting.

You have 2 ways to do this :

1. have mod_rewrite enabled on the Apache side and apply a virtual host configuration like in [this template](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish-community/blob/master/doc/apache2/vhost.template). Make sure you replace the placeholders (%STUFF%) by the correct values.
2. use a .htaccess file in your public_html/web folder : see an [example here](https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/htaccess+example)

Note : being able to use a .htaccess requires that your apache configuration allows it. It's usually the `AllowOverride None|All|...` part of your `<Directory /path/to/public_html/web>`directive : see [Apache Documentation here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: I thought it was a problem of url rewriting, and I created an htaccess too, but didn't worked, so I thought maybe was some else or my htaccess too simple, anyway with that htaccess I solved (solution 2)! Thanks